# Как узнать где лежит js который вызывает обновление?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Если после загрузки страницы происходит аякс-обновление данных, как узнать где лежит js который вызывает обновление.

И как узнать к какому файлу он затем обращается для получения данных.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Открываете отладчик браузера (кнопка F12 обычно).
Далее на примере хрома (аналоги есть в остальных):
Вкладка "Network".
Слева сверху панели отладки нажать на кружок "Recording Network Log" чтобы он был красным.
Чуть правее и ниже поставить "XHR" (показывать только аякс запросы, а не запросы скриптов картинок и прочего).
Инициировать ваш запрос с открытой консолью (страницу обновить скажем).
Начнет обновляться табличка с данными запросов. Выбрать наиболее вероятный, порывшись в данных запросов.
В таблице данных запроса будет Initiator - js файл, вызвавший запрос.

Можно кликнуть на этот js файл и отладчик перешлет вас на строчку отправляющую запрос.
Можно поставить там брейкпоинт, вызвать запрос отправляющий еще раз, и таким образом получить весь коллстек с логикой.

Comment: кстати, для сведения: конкретно в Мозилле случается, что, отфильтровавшись по XHR, можно не увидеть некоторые аякс-запросы; с чем связано - не вникал, но иногда бывает, что приходится порыться в общей портянке;

Answer (score 4):

ну, самое первое - посмотреть сетевые запросы (в мозилле это ctrl-shift-Q, в хроме - сочетание не помню, но можно через меню найти консоль разработчика, и переключиться на вкладку «сеть») найти аякс-подобный запрос (в первую очередь обращаем внимание на POST-запросы, если таких нет - придется порыться в GET-ах), таким образом найдете адрес обращения.

потом идем в отладчик, или в исходники страницы и пробуем искать адрес обращения в коде, или какой-нибудь специфичный параметр, который отличает именно этот запрос от других.